# moment.js - isBetween() method doesn't work consistently

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I have a moment.js code that works well:

```
var startDate = '2015-05-06T19:00:00+0300';
moment(startDate).isBetween(moment(), moment().add(30, 'days'));
// returns true, that's great!
```

But when I start refactoring to make it more readable it fails to work:

```
var today = moment();
var startDate = '2015-05-06T19:00:00+0300'; 
moment(startDate).isBetween(today, today.add(30, 'days'));
// returns false.. but why?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var today = moment();
var startDate = '2015-05-06T19:00:00+0300'; 
moment(startDate).isBetween(today, moment(today).add(30, 'days'));
```

You are passing a reference which you have edited by adding 30 days.

Comment: it bite me too. Thanks